# Cannot find original Android project certificate

Tags: android, certificate, apk, android-keystore

I am trying to upload a new APK file to GooglePlay. I have uploaded several updates for the same app before, but now I get this error:

[image: Screen shot of error on GooglePlay]

I have no idea what's wrong here, especially since I've uploaded new APK's for this app before. Can someone enlighten me on what may be the problem, and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with the certificate (keystore) used to sign the application.

Did you sign the application? Or perhaps you are trying to upload a debug build (straight from eclipse for example)?.

An app needs to be signed with a keystore. They keystore is unique to you. If you loose it, your app can't be signed with another one. Google Play uses that as security, to ensure your app comes from you and not someone else.

Comment: Is it possible to locate this keystone? I'm using a Mac. What I don't understand is that I've uploaded a few updates already, but now it can't find the keystone. Perhaps something happened when I uploaded a new app to GooglePlay recently. Could I have mistakenly used the old keystone for that, and changed it somehow?

Comment: It's definitely possible to find it. You would have had to give it a name when exporting from eclipse. You also would have had to enter a password and alias. Sometimes keystores have a .keystore extension but it's really up to whatever you named it.